# Hiding flash if not enabled and hide jquery if flash is enabled?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, flash, slideshow

Im building a site at the moment which uses flash on the homepage. Ive also got a jquery slideshow. I want to hide the slideslow if flash is enabled and hide the flash is its not enabled, so depending who views it only 1 with be visible.
I take it, it would be done it js?
Any ideas would be greatfully appreciated :]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just embed (nest) the slideshow inside the `<object>` element

if flash is enabled the slideshow won't be seen because the object is correctly initialized by flash plugin, otherwise the markup inside the object tag will be used as a fallback

Starting from [this article](http://latrine.dgx.cz/how-to-correctly-insert-a-flash-into-xhtml) you could write the markup in this way

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
  data="movie.swf" width="300" height="135">
<!-- <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
  codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0"
  width="300" height="135">
  <param name="movie" value="movie.swf" />
<!--><!--dgx-->
  <param name="loop" value="true" />
  <param name="menu" value="false" />

  <!-- fallback here -->
  <div id="slideshow">Here goes your slideshow</div>

</object>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

The main benefit of this technique is that you don't need to add extra logic to check if flash plugin is available or not.